# Kotlin database connectivity error

Tags: database, jdbc, kotlin

Exception in thread "main" kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException    at Kotlin.main(DB.kt:4)

can anyone explain me what is this and what should i do to handle this exception?

```
object Kotlin {
    @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val conn: Connection = null!!
        val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"
        val dbName = "db-01"
        val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance()
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/student")
            println("Connected to the database")
            conn.close()
            println("Disconnected from database")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not without any code, no.

Comment: import java.sql.*
object Kotlin {
  @JvmStatic fun main(args:Array<String>) {
    val conn:Connection = null!!
    val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"
    val dbName = "db-01"
    val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    try
    {
   Class.forName(driver).newInstance()
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/student")
      println("Connected to the database")
      conn.close()
      println("Disconnected from database")
    }
    catch (e:Exception) {
      e.printStackTrace()
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val conn: Connection = null!!`

The `!!` 'casts' a nullable type to a non-null type, if the value is not `null`. If it is `null`, it throws a `NullPointerException`.

Thus, executing `null!!` results in a `NullPointerException`.
Instead, use a `lateinit var`, or make the `Connection` nullable.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine not to initialize local `val`, if you're going to initialize it later:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val conn: Connection
    // ... some code ...
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/student")
}
```

And if you do not need the connection outside of `try` block, you can declare it and initialize it at the same line:

```
try {
    //...
    val conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/student")
    //...
    conn.close()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```